# duplicate INSERT entries in mysql

Tags: php, insert

I have a problem with an application in PHP.
The problem is that it makes a few records in the database. Where is the problem?

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user_list (ip,verified,rank)VALUES ('$ip','$verified','$rank')";
            $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Thank you

Comment: The code shown will insert (or at least attempt to) exactly one record.  (Unless, of course, the SQL injection vulnerability is being used to insert more records.)

Comment: you sure you're not running this on a function or querying twice? Could be something else also, but the Goblins will never tell (their secrets).

Comment: My function works with API and application copies the data in MySQL, but several copies same things and ID are correct. What caused this?

Comment: `ID are correct`, what id? Show how this is being called.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The right way:***

**1)** ***preparing and binding*** values with [mysqli_stmt::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) and [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) functions:

```
// connection object instantiating
$mysqli = new mysqli(......);
...
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO user_list (ip, verified, rank) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt->bindparam('sii', $id, $verified, $rank);
$stmt->execute();
...
```

***2)*** using [INSERT ... IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) OR [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)  syntax to avoid/ignore duplicate inserts